# matrix of expected squared differences of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the matrix

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] & \mathbb{E}[(X_2-X_1)^2] & \dots& \mathbb{E}[(X_n-X_1)^2] \\
        \mathbb{E}[(X_1-X_2)^2] & \mathbb{E}[X_2^2] & \dots& \mathbb{E}[(X_n-X_2)^2] \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \mathbb{E}[(X_1-X_n)^2] & \dots & \dots & \mathbb{E}[X_n^2] 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

where $X_i \sim N(0, \sigma_i)$ and $X_i$ and $X_j$ can be correlated. This seems very familiar to me but I cannot recall where I have seen it and in what context. Has anyone seen it in any applications or as a part of a solution to any problems?

Comment: It is obvious that this Matrix is symmetric. So it can be correlation matrix for some n-dimensional Normal distribution. Is it what you want?

Comment: @DanijelSubotic, this matrix is symmetric but it cannot be a covariance matrix in general. A $2 \times 2$ case shows that if it is a variance covariance matrix, then the off diagonal term in the resulting correlation matrix is of the form $\rho^* = \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2} + \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_2} - 2\rho$ where $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ and $\rho$ are the standard deviation of $X_1$, $X_2$, and $\mathrm{Corr}[X_1, X_2]$, respectively. $\rho^*$ however can be greater than 1 so it can't be a correlation between two other random variables.